# Custom FileInputFormat always assign one filesplit to one slot

Tags: protocol-buffers, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have been writing protobuf records to our s3 buckets. And I want to use flink dataset api to read from it. So I implemented a custom FileInputFormat to achieve this. The code is as below.

```
public class ProtobufInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<StandardLog.Pageview> {
    public ProtobufInputFormat() {
    }

    private transient boolean reachedEnd = false;

    @Override
    public boolean reachedEnd() throws IOException {
        return reachedEnd;
    }

    @Override
    public StandardLog.Pageview nextRecord(StandardLog.Pageview reuse) throws IOException {
        StandardLog.Pageview pageview = StandardLog.Pageview.parseDelimitedFrom(stream);
        if (pageview == null) {
            reachedEnd = true;
        }
        return pageview;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsMultiPaths() {
        return true;
    }
}


public class BatchReadJob {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        String readPath1 = args[0];

        ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();


        ProtobufInputFormat inputFormat =  new ProtobufInputFormat();
        inputFormat.setNestedFileEnumeration(true);

        inputFormat.setFilePaths(readPath1);

        DataSet<StandardLog.Pageview> dataSource = env.createInput(inputFormat);

        dataSource.map(new MapFunction<StandardLog.Pageview, String>() {
            @Override
            public String map(StandardLog.Pageview value) throws Exception {
                return value.getId();
            }
        }).writeAsText("s3://xxx", FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE);
        env.execute();

    }

}
```

The problem is that flink always assign one filesplit to one parallelism slot. In other word, it always process the same number of file split as the number of the parallelism.

I want to know what's the correct way of implementing custom FileInputFormat.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the behavior you're seeing is because `ExecutionJobVertex` calls the `FileInputFormat. createInputSplits()` method with a `minNumSplits` parameter equal to the vertex (data source) parallelism. So if you want a different behavior, then you'd have to override the `createInputSplits` method.

Though you didn't say what behavior you actually wanted. If, for example, you just want one split per file, then you could override the `testForUnsplittable()` method in your subclass of `FileInputFormat` to always return true; it should also set the (protected) `unsplittable` boolean to true.